# Is it possible to get the runbook name within the runbook environments?

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-runbook, predefined-variables

I want to get the Azure runbook name within the environment sandbox of the runbook.

Is it possible to do that? Like, are there any predefined variables that we can get as in the case of Azure  Pipelines?

I have checked a bit the documentation but I couldn't find anything related.

Comment: AFAIK there is no predefined variables that you can use in automation to get the variable. Instead there is a command called [`Get-AzAutomationVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationvariable?view=azps-10.3.0) to retrieve it. Is that works for you? @MoonHorse

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no predefined variables that you can use in automation to get the variable. After a workaround on this, I found a couple of approaches which are listed below.

*Approach-1:*

Using [`Get-AzAutomationVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationvariable?view=azps-10.3.0) to retrieve the predefined variables by storing it in `variables` under `shared resources` of automation account blade as shown.

[image]

```
$Variable = (Get-AzAutomationVariable -AutomationAccountName "newauto" -Name "runbookname" -ResourceGroupName "<resourceGroup>").Name
write-output "variable name is $Variable."
```

[image]

*Note:* *If you want to execute it in azure runbook, perform the same script and it will work as expected.*

*Approach-2:*

Another one is using [`Start-AzAutomationRunbook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/start-azautomationrunbook?view=azps-10.3.0). With this command, you can access the runbook by passing runbook name as a `parameter` in the automation script as given below.

```
$params = @{'runbookname' = 'new'}
Start-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "newauto" -Name "new" -ResourceGroupName "<resourcegroup>" -Parameters $params
```

Comment: I want to get the runbook name within the runbook. Unfortunately, in my case, I cannot pass it as parameter/variable because the parameter name won't be static. The runbook needs to have its own name dynamically.

Comment: In that case you can create a json file to store all the parameters and pass it with the ‘parameters’ argument. @MoonHorse

Comment: Did u give it a try? @MoonHorse

Comment: It won't work for me. Because essentially, the runbook is triggered by a webhook.

Comment: How you are triggering it by a webhook? Using PS command? @MoonHorse

Comment: by the eventgrid